# Wildcard subdomain redirecting to a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect `foo.bar.com` to `bar.com/foo.php`, but I have no idea where to start and everything else has failed me so far. I've tried many things here on StackOverflow, but none of them seem to be working at all (just various Apache errors).

I already have a wildcard subdomain set up from cPanel, but I'm not really sure where to go from here. Is .htaccess even the best option for this?

EDIT: I also want to rewrite the URL from `bar.com/foo.php` to `foo.bar.com`.

Comment: Maybe you should make the wildcard subdomain redirect to something like  `bar.com/redirect.php?subdomain=foo`, and then do it from there with `PHP` and `$_GET`

Comment: @MadsMarquart Hmm, yeah, this is probably a better approach. I don't know how I'd go about grabbing the $_GET variable in .htaccess, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this generic rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%2/%1.php [L,R=302]
```

**EDIT:** To hide the rewritten URL (internal rewrite) use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %1.php [L]
```

Comment: This worked great for redirecting, and seems to suit my needs almost completely. but I actually left something out of my answer. I want to also rewrite the URL to reflect that you're on a subdomain and not the file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Thank you! This worked for subdomains, but when I actually tried going to my root url, it gave me a 404.

Comment: By root url, I mean just `foo.com` with no subdomain.

Comment: ah ok, see my updated answer now. It will skip `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` where `domain.com` is main domain.